# Should Why is Global State so Evil? be closed?

Tags: support, specific-question, closing-questions

So since we've been round about today on Constructive Questions, should [Why is Global State so Evil?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil) be closed?  It is essentially a subjective matter, likely to result in a list, and seems to be geared toward a discussion.

Should I vote to close, merely laugh at the responses, or pile on?

Answer (score 5):

That question is an example of a [good subjective question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/). Yes, such questions might generate a lot of answers and even some discussion in the comments. However, there are criteria that make these types of questions appropriate, and those reasons are outlined in the blog post.

Keep one thing in mind - a question is not judged only on the question itself, but the content and the quality of the answers that it produces. This question isn't asking for a list of things, and the people answering are providing high-quality answers.

Comment: I sort of don't like where you are saying `a question is not judged only on the question itself, but the content and the quality of the answers that it produces`.  I might say that a question can be judged if it **encourages** bad answers, but ultimately I don't like a good question to be discriminated when the answers should be and could be getting mod attention.

Comment: @maple_shaft That's really my point. If someone flags a question, I don't just look at the question. It could be a good question getting bad answers, a bad question getting good answers, a good question getting good answers, or a bad question getting bad answers. Sometimes, the best thing to do is to clean up the answers and leave the question, while other times, it's not really salvageable at all.